# Can we add a second FaceTime account to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages, facetime

I try to add a second FaceTime account on my iPhone to be reachable on two iMessage and FaceTime accounts on the same device.

I have an eSim for my professional use and a normal sim for my personal stuff and I’d like to put some walls between personal and pro accounts and so have a dedicated account for FaceTime and iMessage.

I added my pro account into the Mail >  accounts section, but in the FaceTime settings it’s look like it is not possible to set up two accounts on the same device. Is it possible?

Thanks